# Bing Search API: Getting 401 Acces Denied error while using the right suscription key

Tags: java, azure, android-studio, azure-api-management, bing-api

I am trying to connect to my newly created Bing Search API using Java in Android Studio.

When I execute the `connection.getInputStream()` statement, it returns a 401 error saying "Acces Denied".

The same error is returned when I provide a wrong suscription key on purpose. However, I am sure that the suscription key that I am using is right, as I am copying and pasting it from the Azure control panel, and it is from the only suscription I have (a trial one).

```
URL url = new URL("https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/search" + "?q=" 
    + URLEncoder.encode(input, "UTF-8"));

HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "...");

try {
    InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
}
catch(FileNotFoundException ignore) { //https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/search?q=...
    int code = connection.getResponseCode(); // 401
    String message = connection.getResponseMessage(); // "Acces Denied"
}
```

Comment: Could you please test in postman to request the url with subscription key ?

Comment: @HuryShen sure, but what is that?

Comment: Copy the url to postman and also set the header with `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:xxxx` in postman. Then test request and check the response result.

Comment: How's going?Has your issue got resolved?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the same error while tried to call Bing web search API. I solved this issue by creating a cognitive service instance and use its endpoint and key:

[image]

This is my test code based on yours:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class HTTPtest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Endpoint = "<Endpoint>";
        String key = "<key>";

        String input = "Bill Gates divorce";

        try {
            URL url = new URL(Endpoint + "bing/v7.0/search" + "?q=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "UTF-8"));

            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", key);

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            System.out.println(new String(stream.readAllBytes()));

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Do I have to create a Bing Search service too? What if I have various, depending on the subscription and prices? @StanleyGong

Comment: I was not able to implement your solution. Meanwhile the error has just magically solved. Anyways, thank you very much for your answer! @StanleyGong